# Handle State change in React with ONE handleChange method for both selectFields and TextFields

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I would like to know how I can handle state changes with ONE handleChange method.

I handle two text fields with handleChange, but I cant figure out how I can handle changes on [**SelectField**](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/select-field)  as well, with the same handleChange method.

When change the Spot Type from Kitesurfing to Diving and console.log this.state I get this:

```
form
:
description: "This is a amazing spot in Spain."
name: "Blue water"
spotType: "Kitesurfing"
undefined: undefined <-- this is from the SelectField, when changing from Kitesurfing to Diving..
```

AddASpot.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import TextField from "material-ui/TextField";
import SelectField from "material-ui/SelectField";
import MenuItem from "material-ui/MenuItem";
import RaisedButton from "material-ui/RaisedButton";

class AddASpot extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      form: {
        spotType: "Kitesurfing"
      }
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange = event => {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === "checkbox" ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    const form = Object.assign({}, this.state.form);
    form[name] = value;

    this.setState({ form });
  };

  handleSubmit = () => {
    console.log(this.state);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Add a new Spot</h1>
        <TextField
          name="name"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          hintText="Name of Spot"
        />
        <br />
        <SelectField
          floatingLabelText="Spot Type"
          name="spotType"
          value={this.state.form.spotType}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        >
          <MenuItem value="Diving" primaryText="Diving" />
          <MenuItem value="Kitesurfing" primaryText="Kitesurfing" />
          <MenuItem value="Surfing" primaryText="Surfing" />
          <MenuItem value="Spearfishing" primaryText="Spearfishing" />
        </SelectField>
        <br />
        <TextField
          name="description"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          hintText="Description of the Spot"
          multiLine={true}
          rows={3}
          rowsMax={4}
        />
        <br />
        <RaisedButton
          onClick={this.handleSubmit}
          label="Add Spot"
          primary={true}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AddASpot;
```

Comment: please add plunker/fiddle for it

Answer (score 0):

Your logic inside of the handleChange method needs some reconsidering. It seems you are trying to make things a lot more complicated than they need to be. Your example is hard to reproduce, unless someone wants to build this themselves, which is probably why no one has answered it yet.

I did however get a similar type of example working in Codepen, without the material UI package you are using, as I do not know how to add those packages properly into Codepen.

To hopefully make this easier for you, I just got the select menu working for you, and ignored the other ones for now. Hopefully this will help you visualize how to incorporate the logic to handle the others properly.

Check the pen [here](https://codepen.io/DZuz14/pen/Xaxzzb?editors=1011). You'll see that I changed your handleChange method to two lines of code, without the need for using Object.assign.

If you can get a full working version of your specific example, I'd be glad to change the answer to reflect that, but like I said, it is not easy to reproduce for people on here.

```
  handleChange = event => {
    const value = event.target.value
    this.setState({ form: { spotType: value } })
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not figure out how to handle this with only one method so I created one unique for the SelectFields as this method requires three props.

```
  handleChangeSelectField = (event, index, value) => {
    const form = Object.assign({}, this.state.form);
    form["spotType"] = value;
    this.setState({ form });
  };
```